# Create a Control in Unit Test for WPF application

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, unit-testing

I have a WPF-application with a method which takes in a TextBox and return true or false.  I have created a Test project, but I cannot create an object of a TextBox to test my method. Is it not possible to add a Control like that in a Test-class? I want to do something like this:

```
    [TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        TextBox textBox = New Textbox();
        Assert.AreEqual(MyMethodWithTextBox(textBox), true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you add reference to [PresentationFramework.dll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.aspx) (this is the assembly where WPF `TextBox` class lives). Test project template most likely doesn't include it by itself, as opposed to WPF application project template.